# ElasticSearch Combined with MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, scale

We have an application using Elastic Search & MySQL.

On the ElasticSearch we have content that is searchable.
On our MySQL DB we have content data, events, users, relationships & overall application with logic etc.

However, we find the 2 hard to balance it terms of logic, what to use where, since we don't want to waste on scaleability nor storage.

We do however see that the storage part might have to make way for the scaling.

**Possible options:**

A. Have some data on ES & Some data on MSQL.

B. Run 1 version on ES & 1 identical version on MSQL. 
Doing search related actions on ES and "Content-viewing" on MSQL.

C. Have it all on ES

Worries: That this will give us "unnecessary" load in terms of storage.

D. Other

- *What do you recommend?*

Comment: This question might need to be addressed somewhere else due to it's opinion based nature. Some developers might answer differently based upon many factors. For what it's worth, I would go with option B because there are reliability issues with Elasticsearch. It's really not intended to be a fully robust storage solution as much as  a high-availability, rapidly searchable data store. You can also use ES to store formatted information purely for searching, instead of a 1:1 duplication of your MSQL data

Comment: PS: I'm not flagging this question, just voicing that it might need to be made a little more specific

Comment: I'd say this is fairly straightforward -- ElasticSearch is not a database with the same level of durability and recovery as RDS. There are snapshots, but not point-in-time recovery, like RDS has. All your data should be stored in the database. Although... S3, in this context, with versioning enabled, would also qualify as a suitably durable "database," for storing the authoritative copy of your content as individual S3 objects, if the documents are large and you don't want them in RDS for space reasons... and S3 will scale to essentially any volume.